# Representing Student Attendance JSON data on a Table Using PHP

Tags: php, html, json

I have a json data from a RESTful API, which shows the records of all students with their corresponding attendance in a json array, then i want to populate the marked date such that it matches the number of days on a table using php

This is what I have and tried.
I want the attendance marked be represented under each matched days from the marked_date

```
[
    {
        "id": 18,
        "surname": "Olawale",
        "firstname": "Olamide",
        "othername": "David",        
        "image": "user-0330f9e4e47d34104f581513c1c0c88d.png",
        "current_class": "1",
        "admission_no": "S18/2023",
        "attendance": [
            {
                "id": 4,
                "student_id": "18",
                "admission_no": "S18/2023",
                "class_id": "1",
                "session": "2022/2023",
                "marked": "present",
                "marked_date": "2023-05-15",
                "created_at": "2023-05-15 09:22:28"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "student_id": "18",
                "admission_no": "S18/2023",
                "class_id": "1",
                "session": "2022/2023",
                "marked": "absent",
                "marked_date": "2023-05-12",
                "created_at": "2023-05-12 14:06:55"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 13,
        "surname": "Adekoya",
        "firstname": "adebola",
        "othername": "test",
        "image": "user-b5501140a2a1b70c0f5a1668acdac8b1.jpg",
        "current_class": "1",
        "admission_no": "S13/2023",
        "attendance": [
            {
                "id": 5,
                "student_id": "13",
                "admission_no": "S13/2023",
                "class_id": "1",
                "session": "2022/2023",
                "marked": "present",
                "marked_date": "2023-05-15",
                "created_at": "2023-05-15 09:22:28"
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "student_id": "13",
                "admission_no": "S13/2023",
                "class_id": "1",
                "session": "2022/2023",
                "marked": "present",
                "marked_date": "2023-05-12",
                "created_at": "2023-05-12 14:13:16"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

The Php Code for looping the records

```
                      if( $results ) :
                          $x = 0;
                          // days counts the number of days in a month to 31
                          $days = range(1,31);
                          foreach ($results as $row) : 
                            echo '
                            <tr>
                             <th scope="row">'.implode(" ", [$row['surname'],$row['firstname'],$row['othername']]).'</th>';
                            // attendance   
                            $attends = $row['attendance'];   
                            for ($a=0; $a < count($days); $a++) {
                              if( isset($attends[$a]['student_id']) ) {
                                $attend = $attends[$a];
                                $marked = $attend['marked'];
                                $marked_date  = $attend['marked_date'];
                                $d = date('j', strtotime($marked_date));
                                if ( $days[$d-1] == $d ) {
                                  echo '<td>'.$marked.'</td>';
                                } else {
                                  echo '<td><span>-</span></td>';
                                }
                              } else {
                                echo '<td><span>-</span></td>';
                              }
                            }
                            echo '</tr>';
                          endforeach;
                        endif;
```

resulting attendance table image
[image]

Comment: So what's the issue currently? Please explain the specific problem with the current output, compared to your expectation. This information is missing - are we supposed to infer it? Please [edit] your question to be clearer. Thanks.

Comment: `if( isset($attends[$a]['student_id']) )` makes little sense. Your `attendance` arrays do not use the day number in the month as key, they have a normal zero-based integer index. You will either have to "search" the `attendance` data for an item where they day portion of the `marked_date` matches `$a`; or you will have to _transform_ those attendances into arrays that _do_ use the day number as key first.

Comment: Thank you ADyson, the issue here is that from the image attached marked part are the marked date where each student is present and absent and it meant to be under each number the marked date I have for Adekoya is 2023-05-15 and 2023-05-12 and Olawale is 2023-05-15 and 2023-05-12 which it supposed to be under 12 and 15, will appreciate your help

Comment: @CBroe, if I could get your explanation right, when I tired using the day number as a key in the attendance it generates multiple records and extends beyond 31 days, the attendance are already in array, how do I transform the attendance into an array using the day number

Comment: _"if I could get your explanation right"_ - sounds like you probably didn't, because: _"when I tired using the day number as a key in the attendance it generates multiple records and extends beyond 31 days"_ - no idea how that could be happening, when you are still looping over `$days = range(1,31);` to create your output? You need to show us what you actually tried, we can't possibly tell what is actually going on based on nothing but such a vague verbal description.

Comment: _"how do I transform the attendance into an array using the day number"_ - in the most basic form, you can do that by looping over your existing array, and then adding each item into a new result array, _specifying_ the key while you do so (https://3v4l.org/iDBE2). A bit more sophisticated approach could be using `array_combine` and `array_column` (but the latter is only suitable to extract a complete value from your array, so you could only get the full `marked_date` value using that - so it would need an additional `array_walk` call first to "reduce" those values to just the day.)

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for your help, it really helps. Now working as expected!